# Files on Windows but Symlinks on Linux?

Tags: dual-boot, symlink, ntfs, pop-os

I've recently started dualbooting Pop_OS and Windows, and it's been generally difficult, but this issue is, at best, completely confounding. Some seemingly random files are displayed as broken symbolic links under Linux, despite being normal, perfectly functional files under Windows.

As an example, here's an image of my copy of FNAF Security Breach under Windows. I have Link Shell Extension installed, so if it were a link, it would pretty easy to see.
[image: Image of file explorer with overlayed properties window of fnaf9.exe, showing no signs of being a symbolic link]

Here's the same file as seen in Pop_OS.
[image: Image of Nautilus with overlayed properties window of fnaf9.exe, showing a broken symblink with the destination listed as "unknown reparse tag 0x80000017"]

To clarify, I did make sure the files are intact under Windows by running the game, and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: The properties dialog shows the problem - that file uses a [NTFS reparse tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_reparse_point#System_compression), and it seems the Linux NTFS driver doesn't support that reparse tag.